# A minimal code webpart that displays a single picked item from a list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts, sharepoint-designer

I'm not sure this is possible, but figured I´d give it a shot. First a few pre-requeistes and environment details:

- I´m using SharePoint 2010, SharePoint
  Designer 2010, VS 2010
- I want to create as little code as
  possible, preferably, create it all via UI or Designer
- use out of the box components as much
  as possible

Here is What I want to do:

- Have a custom list with custom columns (easy part)
- Create a webpart with an edit interface to select a single item from this list
- This same webpart when visible would display the contents of this selected item in a given layout

I know I can do this creating a custom web part and code it all from scratch, I guess my main question is, is there a way to do this with less code and more out of the box components in SP2010. If not, I guess I'm left with lots of C# code.

Any tips, or pointers in this direction will be most welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for the update. In the end, i had to create quite a bit of code to get this to work:

- created a web part that enumerates
  the content type,
- creates a light box that has a picker
- then stores the ID of the content in a column

Not the easiest way,but the only way I could get it working. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the [Data Form Web Part](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/web-parts-for-views-and-forms-in-sharepoint-designer-2010-HA101805424.aspx#_Toc245608912).

Unfortunately, I can't find any good tutorials for 2010, but hopefully the steps should be similar to [setting it up in 2007](http://www.endusersharepoint.com/2009/10/12/creating-mailing-lists-for-sharepoint-sites-and-blogs-no-code-required-part-3-more-customizations-to-the-subscription-form-using-dataformwebpart/).

Comment: Any thoughts on how I would have the administrator use the data form web part to select only ONE item from the list to be displayed? thanks,

Comment: @mateuscb: I'm pretty sure when you select the data source then you can choose to insert the fields for a single item Form.

Comment: @ Kit Menke, wasn't able to get that working. I can choose what fields i want to display, but I can't seem to find a way to choose on instance of an item from the list (Ex, [bob, joe, lisa] I want to choose [joe] and have it show up in the web part.